# JSON Object Navigation

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm currently having an issue with parsing json.
Here's my code:

```
url = f"https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/{hashtag}/?__a=1"
response = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"})
j = json.loads(response.text)
id = j['graphql']['hashtag']['edge_hashtag_to_media']['edges']['node']['owner']['id']
uname = get_username(id)
pos = 0
for position in j:
  for username in j:
    with open("scraped.txt", "a+") as f:
      f.write(f"{uname}\n")

  pos += 1
```

When running, I am getting the error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`
I have already asked someone why I would be getting this error, and they said it might be because the json I'm trying to parse doesn't exist, but as far as I can tell, it does.

The line which it says the error is occuring from is:
`id = j['graphql']['hashtag']['edge_hashtag_to_media']['edges']['node']['owner']['id']`

Comment: One of the nested elements is a list, and you assume it's a dict. Most likely, `edges`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the one of the object in the path ['graphql']['hashtag']['edge_hashtag_to_media']['edges']['node']['owner']['id'] is list not a json(dict)

please upload full j

it must be a list

[image]

here, the edges object is not a json but a list

Comment: I might sound kinda stupid right now, but what do you mean by `please upload full j`

Comment: we can't see j, the json object. If I can see it, I can tell exact point in which problem occurs

Comment: Oh, you can just use the url I provided, but add the hashtag ex - https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/fitness/?__a=1

Comment: @Stress_, so you need to specify the index of edges object like j['graphql']['hashtag']['edge_hashtag_to_media']['edges'][42 for example]['node']['owner']['id']

Answer (score 0):

Between lines 3 and 4, try printing out what the variable `j` is. This way, you can see the kind of object you are working with. Most likely the issue is that you are trying to parse through `j` incorrectly. You may need to do something like `j.graphql` or use `{}`.

**So your next steps are:**

1. Print out `j` between lines 3 and 4
2. Figure out the method of parsing `j` requires (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)
3. Store the properties of `j` you would like in the `id` variable using method from step 2